# Turning off new ADO format

Tags: azure-devops

Looking for help from someone knowledgeable about ADO. I need to install onebranch in our teams ADO organization. In order to do that I have to turn *off* thge new URL format. I'm wondering what the repercussions will be of turning that off. Will it break links? ANy other issues I should know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/work-with-urls?view=azure-devops&tabs=http):

> With the introduction of Azure DevOps Services, organizational resources and APIs are now accessible via either of the following URLs:
>
> - [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D) (new)
> - https://{organization}.visualstudio.com (legacy)
>
> Regardless of when the organization was created, users, tools, and integrations can interact with organization-level REST APIs using either URL. As the developer of an extension, integration, or tool that interacts with Azure DevOps Services, it is important to understand how to properly work with URLs made available to your code and how to properly form URLs when calling REST APIs.

Both links give you the same so you should not get any repercussions.